# move data from one column to another mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am wanting to move data from one column to another in a MySQL table.

Here is my code:

```
   $sDate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

mysql_query( "   UPDATE users
SET 
  logintimelast = logintime 

AND 
  logintime = '$sDate'");
```

However this does not update either column?

Comment: Seems you missed the WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your syntax is wrong.  `lotintime AND logintime = '$sDate'` is a boolean expression.

```
SET
    logintimelast = logintime,
    logintime = '$sDate'
```

Your query is vulnerable to injection.  You should stop using `ext/mysql` and use properly parameterized queries with `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: And you (OP) should add error reporting, which would've told you about the invalid SQL.